# Elephant.io server error with Php( An error occurred while trying to establish a connection to the server)

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have a question for you, I'm using **socket.io** and **elephant.io** in my **php application**, but I've been dealing with the error I got by elephant.io for almost 2 days. Is there something I did wrong? Below are the errors and codes I got.

**MY ERROR**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0kf3.png)

**MY INDEX.PHP**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;

$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:9090'));
$client->initialize();
$client->emit('send-message', [
    'name' => 'john',
    'surname' => 'doe'
]);
$client->close();
```

**MY APP.JS**

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    }
});
io.on('connection',function (socket){
    console.log('connected');
   socket.on('send-message',function (data){
       console.log(data);
       io.emit('message',data);
   })
   socket.on('disconnect',function (){
       console.log('disconnected')
   })
})
server.listen(9090);
```

**MY SOCKET.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.js" 
integrity="sha512-WL6WGKMPBiM9PnHRYIn5YEtq0Z8XP4fkVb4qy7PP4vhmYQErJ/dySyXuFIMDf1eEYCXCrQrMJfkNwKc9gsjTjA==" 
crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:9090');
socket.on('message',function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
socket.emit('send-message',{
    "name":"johnHTML",
    "surname": "doeHTML"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the error message as text besides the image, it is important for other users' future search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this error once. I searched like you but couldn't find it. I tried many different methods, none of them worked. As a last resort I changed the version of the **"socket.io"** library to **2.2.0** and it worked. you should try this

Comment: great , fixing same issue for an hour this downgrade help me